# Проверка на наличие элемента в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы, index

Как правильно проверить на наличие элемента в массиве:

```
int radius = 50;
float cellSize = (float)radius * (float)Math.Sqrt(1 / 2);
Vector3[,] grid = new Vector3[gridWidth, gridHeight];
for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x += (int)cellSize)
{
  for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z += (int)cellSize)
  {
     grid[x, z] = new Vector3((float)x, 0, (float)z);
   }
}
...
int i = (int)(vec.x / cellSize),
  j = (int)(vec.z / cellSize),
  i0 = Math.Max(i - 2, 0),
  j0 = Math.Max(j - 2, 0),
  i1 = Math.Min(i + 3, gridWidth),
  j1 = Math.Min(j + 3, gridHeight);

for (j = j0; j < j1; ++j)
{
 int o = j * gridWidth;
 for (i = i0; i < i1; ++i)
 {
   if (grid[o, i])) //что тут писать в условии?
   {
                     
    }
  }
}
```

Перевожу этот [код](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3). C javascript на C#

Comment: Проверять наличие лучше не в массиве, а, например, в  HashSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
 Array.IndexOf(grid, searchedObject);
```

для возврата индекса элемента в массиве

А вообще дополните вопрос с элементом который вы ищите чтоб понять критерий поиска

Comment: я перебираю элементы массива, мне надо не получить элемент а просто проверить существует элемент в двумерном массиве по индексу... сейчас, поправлю вопрос

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос ...

Comment: Так вот если у вас есть объект в руках то IndexOf вам вернет индекс если есть такой.

Comment: понял ... что предлагаете . спасибо

Comment: В документации указано  возвращает -1 если не нашёл

Comment: Да проверяете на >= 0 и в бой